# Websockets in Suave

Tags: websocket, f#, suave

I've been looking into using websockets with the Suave web server. Unfortunately, it's not very well documented, and all I've managed to find was this: https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/tree/master/examples/WebSocket

However, that only shows the websocket responding to the client that made the request, and I want to basically have the socket respond to all connected clients. Something like a chat server.

I've used SignalR in the past, but would prefer to avoid it for this.

So, how would I go about having the Suave server send data to all connected websocket clients?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suave doesn't provide anything like that out of the box, however you can easily extend the example to do so.

The socket handler `ws` passed to the `handShake` function can pass the client information outside, and you can build a send/broadcast API around it.

The `ws` function can be modified for example like this

```
let ws onConnect onDisconnect (webSocket: WebSocket) (context: HttpContext) =
    let loop () = (* the socket logic stays the same *)

    socket {
        onConnect webSocket context
        try
            do! loop ()
        finally
            onDisconnect context
    }
```

Then it's up to you to inject the `onConnect` and `onDisconnect` handles to register/unregister clients.

I use a `MailboxProcessor` to serialize the Connect/Disconnect/Send operations, alternatively it's easy to use Reactive Extensions, or a shared mutable concurrent storage like `ConcurrentDictionary`...